# How to delete SQL record in back end database, VBA, Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to delete all records in the field "pathway" in the table CUSTOMER that is in the backend (offline) database.

So far I have this, but it does not work with DELETE statement

```
Sub delpath()

Dim dbinputC As String

dbinputC = "[" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CUSTOMER.accdb" & "]"

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE pathway FROM " & dbinputC & ".SPECPATH (WHERE pathway <> Null);"

End Sub
```

Or

```
Dim dbinputC As String

dbinputC = "'" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CUSTOMER.accdb" & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE pathway FROM SPECPATH (WHERE pathway <> Null) IN " & dbinputC & ";"
```

Comment: Adding to the answer you already got: `<> Null` is not really a valid comparison. Use `Is Not Null` instead. `<> Null` always returns Null since comparing against null always returns null, thus making your query delete no records.

Comment: Thank you! And how about the path? It tells me that there is some issue with the FROM statement. Could you identify where is the error, please?

Comment: Second attempt is close to valid, only `In` comes before `WHERE` (so move that `WHERE` to the end) and remove the parentheses from the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Private Sub Test_Clear_Data
     Clear_Data "SPECPATH", "Pathway"
 End Sub


 Private Sub Clear_Data(Table_Name as String, Column_Name As String)
 Dim Connection_Path As String
 Dim Source_Recset As Object
 'Assumes "Clear_Data_Query" already exists
   Set Source_Recset = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Clear_Data_Query")
   Source_Recset.SQL = CStr("Update " & Table_Name & " SET [" & Table_Name & "].[" & Column_Name & "] = NULL WHERE [" & Table_Name & "].[" & Column_Name & "] IS NOT Null" & ";")
   Source_Recset.Execute
   Source_Recset.Close
End Sub
```

Source_Recset.SQL should get "UPDATE SPECPATH SET [SPECPATH].[Pathway] = NULL Where [SPECPATH].[Pathway] IS NOT NULL;" If table is SPECPATH and Column Name is Pathway
Since you are referencing an offline database i included code to append the table temporarily and remove it after (code is not needed if you leave the table defined in the access file"

```
Private Sub Clear_Offline_Data(Share_Folder as String, File_Name as String, Table_Name as String, Column_Name As String)
Dim Connection_Path As String
Dim Source_Recset As Object
Dim Destination_Recset As Object

'Create Table To Network Data
   Set Destination_Recset = currentDB.CreateTableDef("Offline_Data_Table")
   Connection_Path = ";DATABASE=" & ShareFolder & "\" & File_Name
   Destination_Recset.Connect = Connection_Path
   Destination_Recset.SourceTableName = Table_Name

   currentDB.TableDefs.Append Destination_Recset
   currentDB.TableDefs.Refresh
'Create Temp_Data From Network Table
   Set Source_Recset = CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("Clear_Data_Query")
   Source_Recset.SQL = CStr("Update Offline_Data_Table SET [Offline_Data_Table]." & Column_Name & " = NULL WHERE [Offline_Data_Table]." & Column_Name & " IS NOT Null" & ";")
   Source_Recset.Execute
   Source_Recset.Close
'Remove Table to network data 
   currentDB.TableDefs.Delete "Offline_Data_Table"
   currentDB.TableDefs.Refresh
'Remove Query
   currentDB.QueryDefs.Delete "Clear_Data_Query"
   currentDB.QueryDefs.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, looks helpful, I will definitely test it !

Answer (score 0):

A *delete* query deletes rows, not fields.

You must use an *update* query that updates field pathway.

Comment: Hi, that is precisely what I want. To delete all records (rows) in the field "pathway". This one happens to be in another database. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Rows (records) are in tables. Tables have columns (fields), Your statement makes no sense. Do you want to delete all rows in a table where the field pathways is null?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it worked after all:

```
Sub delpath()

Dim dbinputC As String

 dbinputC = "[" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CUSTOMER.accdb" & "]"
 DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE pathway FROM " & dbinputC & ".SPECPATH WHERE pathway Is Not Null;"

 End Sub
```